# Get difference between two dates with inputs of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, date-difference

Want to get the difference between the two dates.

**Input:** `Dec 2016 to Feb 2018`(string)

**Expected Output:** `1 year 2 months`

is any optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the moment library, and it's [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) function to get the same result you desire.

Here are the implementations for the above question:

```js
function dateDiff(d1, d2) {
  return moment.duration(Math.abs(moment(d1, 'MMM YYYY').diff(moment(d2, 'MMM YYYY'))))
}

let diffDuration = dateDiff('Dec 2016', 'Nov 2019')
diffDuration

var years = diffDuration.years(), months = diffDuration.months();
console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```